# How get users emails in though query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

Parse doesn't return users emails in query response, but I need get emails in basic `find` query, how can I get it?

Comment: Do your users want you to see their emails? Did you ask them first? Do they know what you’re doing with their emails? I wouldn’t be surprised if the users emails are protected. Almost certainly they will be protected from other users.

Comment: I'm create admin panel for mobile app, and administrator need to see emails of users.

Comment: Are your admin users on the correct ACL for access to users emails?

Comment: How can I check it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emails are not accessible for security reasons by no-one. Only a call with the masterKey can read the emails from the users table.

This is a preventive security measure in order to avoid data leaks.

Comment: where i can read about queries with masterKey? Can't find anything about this in the docs...

Comment: You can probably have a look here https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#using-parse-on-different-platforms and here https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#implementing-business-logic-in-cloud-code.

You can implement this in a cloud function, protected that would ensure the user has the proper authentication level / roles.

Answer (score 1):

Email access is restricted for security reasons, but using a master key will give access.

Instead of

```
query.find()
```

add a master key request in the find

```
query.find({useMasterKey:true})
```